# If $a\le f(x)\le b<0$, why $\int_0^t f(x) g(x) dx +\int_t^T f(x) g(x) dx\le a\int_0^t g(x) dx +b\int_t^T g(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $T>0$ be fixed $f, g$ be continuous real valued functions such that
$$a\le f(x)\le b<0\quad\text{ and }\quad \int_0^t g(x) dx >0, \quad \int_t^T g(x) dx <0$$
for some constants $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and a fixed $t\in [0, T]$.

Could someone please help me in justifying the inequality
$$\int_0^t f(x) g(x) dx +\int_t^T f(x) g(x) dx\le a\int_0^t g(x) dx +b\int_t^T g(x) dx?$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this statement is true:

Let $t=T=9$ such that the inequality becomes $\int_0^9 f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x\leq a\int_0^9g(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Let $$g(x)=\begin{cases}8&t\leq1\\-1&t\geq1+\varepsilon\end{cases}$$ and $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-1&t\leq1\\-2&t\geq1+\varepsilon\end{cases}$$ where the part with $t\in(1,1+\varepsilon)$ is filled such that the functions are nicely continuous.

Then (ignoring the part $t\in(1,1+\varepsilon)$ for the moment) we have $$\int_0^9f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x\approx\int_0^1-8\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1+\varepsilon}^92\mathrm{d}x\approx-8+16=8\gg0$$ and $$a\int_0^9g(x)\mathrm{d}x=-2\left(\int_0^18\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1+\varepsilon}^9-1\mathrm{d}x\right)\approx-2\varepsilon\approx0$$

So we see $\int_0^9f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x\gg0\approx a\int_0^9g(x)\mathrm{d}x$, contradicting your statement

Comment: The statement would be true if we had $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\leq t$ and $g(x)\leq0$ for all $x\geq t$.

Comment: student91 thank you for your answer. Actually, $g(x)\ge 0$ for $0\le x\le t$ and $g(x)<0$ for $t< x\le T$ is exactly the case I am interested in. Could you please explain why in this case is true? (I am editing the question).

Comment: student91, it seems not correct not to accept your answer because of my forgetfulness in asking the question. I will accept yours, but I am posting a new question with all the correct hypotheses.

Comment: student91, here the new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582634/if-a-le-fx-le-b0-and-gx-ge-0-for-0-le-x-le-t-gx0-for-t-x-le-t

Answer (score 1):

this is clearly wrong, because `a` can be a huge minus number and it would make the right part of equation a huge minus.

I'm gonna assume that you made a typo in the right side of inequation and you meant this because I've seen this before:

$$b\int_0^t g(x) dx + a\int_t^T g(x) dx$$
but this is also wrong :D,
here is the counterexample:

$T = 4, t = 2, a = -10, b = -1$

$ g(x) = 1.1, f(x) = -9$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$,

$g(x) = -1, f(x) = -2$ for $x$ in $(1,2)$,

$g(x) = -1.1, f(x) = -9$ for $x$ in $(2,3)$,

$g(x) = 1, f(x) = -2$ for $x$ in $(3,4)$

for simplicity you can compute on this simplified version of you inequation:
$$\int_t^T (f(x)-a)g(x) dx \le \int_0^t (b-f(x))g(x) dx$$